# Abbreviate Long Table with Kable/kableExtra?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I'm getting into making HTML documents using Knitr. I would like to include an abbreviated version of my data in the report a la the data.table package. In R, when we use the data.table package, long tables get abbreviated via ellipsis. For instance:

```
> data.table(iris)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

However, if I try to use `kable(iris)`, the whole table (150 lines) is reproduced. I would like to reproduce the behavior of data.table via kable/kableExtra but I'm not sure how.

At the moment, I'm trying to generate an HTML document, however it would also be nice to know how to do it in LaTeX for future reference.

Comment: Would `kable(head(iris, 10))` be good enough?

Comment: That's my fallback for now. Was hoping for something more comprehensive

Comment: So with the ellipsis, or some kind of indicator that the table is being truncated? What specific things are you looking for in the output?

Comment: The first n (say 5) rows, some marker that there is a break in the table, then the last n rows. Like the data.table output.

Comment: There is a row_spec argument in kableExtra that lets you enter additional latex or css code to put in a row. I feel like that is the way to do it, but can't get it to work.